# How to set the CSS of an img inside a li inside a ul inside a class?

Tags: html, css

In my html file, I have a navigation bar at the top of my page start starts off like this:

```
    <div class="“topNav">
      <ul>
        <li><img src="assets/map.png"> <a href="locations.html">Locations</a></li>
        <li><img src="assets/length.png"> <a href="length.html">Length</a></li>
     </ul>
   </div>
```

And so on.

And in my CSS I tried

```
.topNav img {
  width: 10%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Except that img is too far deep (inside a li tag inside a ul tag) to be noticed or something. I want my topNav's images to be 10%, but not ALL images on my page. I have other images in the lower part of my page, and I have other style plans for them.

Comment: (1) Your CSS is right. (2) "*I want my topNav's images to be 10%..*" -- 10% of what?

Comment: Did you try adding a width and height to an image in img tag itself?

Comment: Your class topNav has a `“` in front of it, maybe a typo?

Comment: @djil is absolutely right!

Comment: @WitVault: Do not edit the question to change the original code posted by Op. It changes the very meaning (*or probably the only cause of problem*) of this question. Only the Op has the prerogative to decide whether to edit *that* particular part or not.

Comment: **NOTE *to reviewers*** as @Abhitalks stated, fixing the typo might make the whole question meaningless, I've re-put the **`“`** again, you may consider *voting to close* the question just do *not* fix the cause of the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your HTML, you have an extra **`“`** here

```
<div class="“topNav">
```

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/ymabbm57/)

```css
.topNav img {
  border:2px green solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="topNav">
  <ul>
    <li><img src="//placehold.it/100x50?text=img-1"> <a href="locations.html">Locations</a></li>
    <li><img src="//placehold.it/100x50?text=img-2"> <a href="length.html">Length</a></li>
    <li><img src="//placehold.it/100x50?text=img-3"> <a href="locations.html">Locations</a></li>
    <li><img src="//placehold.it/100x50?text=img-4"> <a href="length.html">Length</a></li></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: ah! How embarrassing. I was afraid it was gong to be a typo x_x

Comment: well, it happens, sometimes it needs double -*or triple*- checking, and maybe a mug of coffee :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.topNav > ul>li>img` OR `.topNav ul li img` Anyone will work.

Comment: the difference between your selector and the `.topNav img` in the OP is that you specify images nested inside the `li` elements only and not other images nested inside the `.topNav` *but* outside the `ul`, but the `.topNav img` works just fine otherwise

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @pritesh you code has a typo `<div class="“topNav">` should be `<div class="topNav">`

Hope that is the reason it's not working.

Comment: @ Mi-creativity I didn't mean you have a typo. I wanted to mention Pritesh and the main question has a typo. Your answer is just right.

Comment: Sure, this why I deleted my comment after you updated the answer